# Correct structure for github libraries

Tags: php, git, github, composer-php

I wrote a cURL-class that I wanted to share on github and also make available through composer. I successfully put my lib on github https://github.com/tzfrs/SimpleCurl, but I still have problems understanding the correct folder structure.

I currently have it like that:

- The git repository is named `"SimpleCurl"`
- The repository contains a folder named `src/`
- The `src/` folder has the file `SimpleCurl.php` which is the class `SimpleCurl`
- The `SimpleCurl` class however, is in the namespace `tzfrs/Util/`
- The composer.json file contains the following information

`"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "tzfrs\\Util\\": "src/"
    }
}`

Now, my problem of understanding is: Is it okay that the `SimpleCurl.php`-file lies directly in the folder `src/`? Or must it be in the folder `src/tzfrs/Util` in this git repository?

In other words, do I put the vendor name and main namespace as a folder structure also into my projects? Or would I only put the subnamespacenames into the file?

As an example: Let's say my class `SimpleCurl` is not in the namespace `tzfrs/Util/` but in the namespace `tzfrs/Util/Curl`

Would I need to add the namespace `Curl` as a folder into the src folder since it is a Subnamespacename?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your library follows PSR-4 it is ok to have SimpleCurl.php inside "src" using that autoload configuration. There is no need to replicate the namespace as a folder structure, that is something you can see in many PSR-0 libraries, but PSR-0 was deprecated.

If you want to have the class `SimpleCurl` in the namespace `tzfrs\Util\Curl`, then you only need to create a folder called `Curl` that should contain your `SimpleCurl.php`. Everything in `src` will be appended to your prefix, that you defined as `tzfrs\Util`.

Take a look to [Battle of the Autoloaders: PSR-0 vs. PSR-4](http://www.sitepoint.com/battle-autoloaders-psr-0-vs-psr-4/).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This helps very much. So basically, we can go out and say: vendorname(tzfrs) and namespacename(util) don't go into the src folder, subnamespacenames(Curl) do!

This helped!